# How to start the GPS positioning in background thread?

Tags: android, android-location

I need to retrieve the current location using GPS in separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS works asynchronously you don't need to call in separate thread, GPS does not freeze the User interface when getting the positions. Best is you can use a progressDialog and dismiss the progressDialog after you get the positions.

Answer (score 1):

study following code,

```
public class LocListener implements LocationListener {
    private static double lat =0.0;
    private static double lon = 0.0;
    private static double alt = 0.0; 
    private static double speed = 0.0;

    public static double getLat()
    {
        return lat;
    }

    public static double getLon() 
    {
        return lon;
    }

    public static double getAlt()
    {
        return alt;
    }

    public static double getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        alt = location.getAltitude();
        speed = location.getSpeed(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

now use this code for starting gps in thread.

```
new Thread ( new Runnable()
{
     public void run()
     {
        locationManager = ( LocationManager ) getSystemService ( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
            locationListener = new LocListener();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates ( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener );
     }
}).start();
```

Comment: I used the same procedure but I got error as Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Hi Arjun, I fixed some code formatting for you -- didn't do anything except add some spaces so it displays properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

private void turnGPSOff(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```